# Incrementing 2D Arrays vertically and horizontally?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, increment

I am trying to make a method where a 2D array is created in the main, which can be any dimension. After that, we are supposed to make 2 methods, one which increments each next value in the array by a given number labeled step. One method is supposed to increment the rows, and the other increments it by columns.

This is what I have:

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    int [][] fillRightArray = new int [5][8];
    fillRight(fillRightArray, 2);

    int [][] fillDownArray = new int[5][8];
    fillDown(fillDownArray, -2);
```

For the fill right method, this is the what the output should be:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
18 20 22 24... //all the way to 80, since the array has 40 elements (40*2=80)
```

This is my method:

```
 public static void fillRight (int [][] fillRightArray, int step){

    for (int i = 0; i< fillRightArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j< fillRightArray[i].length; j++){
           fillRightArray[i][j] += step*(j+1);



            System.out.print(fillRightArray[i][j] + " ");

        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

But for some reason, my output is:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
```

Any idea as to why this is happening? Same thing happens when I go with the fillDown method, the output is supposed to be:

```
 2 12 22....
 4 14 24....
 6 16 26....
 8 18 28....
 10 20 30.... all the way to 80
```

But instead I get:

```
2  2  2  2  2
4  4  4  4  4
6  6  6  6  6
8  8  8  8  8
10 10 10  10  10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you aren't taking into account the previous cell.

Your logic for determining the value of a specific cell is `fillRightArray[i][j] += step*(j+1);` .

This line only considers the value of j to determine the value of a cell within your array, when it should also consider the value of i (explicitly or implicitly).

You should add a counter that keeps track of how many cells you have set, and set the next cells value based on the number of cells that have already been set.

Your fillRight method should instead look like this:

```
public static void fillRight (int [][] fillRightArray, int step){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< fillRightArray.length; i++){
       for (int j = 0; j< fillRightArray[i].length; j++){
           count++;
           fillRightArray[i][j] += step*count;
           System.out.print(fillRightArray[i][j] + " ");
       }
       System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're constantly repeating the same work and going back to 0 each time.

In your fillRight, each row is doing 2,4,6,8,10 because you're doing step*(j+1), where j resets to 0 after each iteration of the loop. You need to find a way to include i as well as j when setting the value, or just have a counting variable that is incremented each step

Like this:

```
step += 2
fillRightArray[i][j] = step
```

That way you don't need to worry about position.